# Is it possible to disable spellcheck for Coda but leave it enabled for other applications?

Tags: macos, mac, coda, spellcheck

I use Coda as web editor, and I usually have to mix Italian and English nouns and phrases. I don't want spellcheck on (as I use programming-related words such as `uid` and `pid`), so I'd like to deactivate it.

At the same time, though, I'd like to have it enabled everywhere else on my computer.

It appears that Mac OS X doesn't have a way to enable spellcheck for some applications but disable it for others.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just right click in the working tab, select Spelling and uncheck the option "Check Spelling While Typing"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible (I doubt it), but here's a workaround: set a keystroke for the spellcheck menu item in System Preferences so you can easily turn it off or on.